# Converting a time series into start & end dates using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm simply looking for a more intuitive and faster way to get start and end times of uninterrupted time sequences. Here's a reproducible example as well as my way of doing it for the time being:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = ['1999-01-01 00:00:00', '1999-01-01 01:00:00', '1999-01-01 02:00:00',
        '1999-01-10 10:00:00', '1999-01-10 11:00:00', '1999-01-10 12:00:00', '1999-01-10 13:00:00',
        '1999-01-20 17:00:00', '1999-01-20 18:00:00', '1999-01-20 19:00:00']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['time'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# Conversion:
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start Date', 'End Date'])
new_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['End Date'])

df['diff'] = df['time'].diff(1)
df['diff2'] = df['diff'].shift(-1)

new_df['Start Date'] = df['time'].loc[df['diff'] != pd.to_timedelta(1, unit ='h')].reset_index(drop = True)
new_df2['End Date'] = df['time'].loc[df['diff2'] != pd.to_timedelta(1, unit ='h')].reset_index(drop = True)

new_df['End Date'] = new_df2['End Date']
new_df['Duration [Hours]'] = (new_df['End Date'] - new_df['Start Date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

print(new_df)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
           Start Date            End Date  Duration [Hours]
0 1999-01-01 00:00:00 1999-01-01 02:00:00               2.0
1 1999-01-10 10:00:00 1999-01-10 13:00:00               3.0
2 1999-01-20 17:00:00 1999-01-20 19:00:00               2.0
```

Any kind of help will be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to create a `group` column indicating which group each row belongs to. This can be done by using `shift` and `cumsum`. After that, we can simply use `groupby` to create the wanted columns.

```
df['group'] = (df['time'].shift(1) != df['time'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).cumsum()
df = df.groupby('group')['time'].agg(['first', 'last', 'count'])
df['count'] = df['count'] - 1

df.columns = ['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Duration [Hours]']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

We need to remove 1 from the count value since it's the time we want, not simply the number of rows in each group. The last two lines are simply for cleanup to match the wanted output dataframe.

Result:

```
             Start Date            End Date Duration [Hours]
0   1999-01-01 00:00:00 1999-01-01 02:00:00                2
1   1999-01-10 10:00:00 1999-01-10 13:00:00                3
2   1999-01-20 17:00:00 1999-01-20 19:00:00                2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the date of the `time` column and then reduce them with their `first` and `last` values. Named aggreagation allows to put the new names right away:

```
new_df = (df.groupby(df.time.dt.date)
            .agg(**{"Start Date": ("time", "first"), "End Date": ("time", "last")}))
```

which gives

```
>>> new_df

                    Start Date            End Date
time
1999-01-01 1999-01-01 00:00:00 1999-01-01 02:00:00
1999-01-10 1999-01-10 10:00:00 1999-01-10 13:00:00
1999-01-20 1999-01-20 17:00:00 1999-01-20 19:00:00
```

Then you can calculate the time difference between end & start dates by seconds and convert it to hours:

```
diff_in_secs = (new_df["End Date"] - new_df["Start Date"]).dt.total_seconds()
new_df["Duration [Hours]"] = diff_in_secs / 3600
```

to get

```
>>> new_df

                    Start Date            End Date  Duration [Hours]
time
1999-01-01 1999-01-01 00:00:00 1999-01-01 02:00:00               2.0
1999-01-10 1999-01-10 10:00:00 1999-01-10 13:00:00               3.0
1999-01-20 1999-01-20 17:00:00 1999-01-20 19:00:00               2.0
```

To exactly match your output, you can reset the index:

```
>>> new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> new_df

           Start Date            End Date  Duration [Hours]
0 1999-01-01 00:00:00 1999-01-01 02:00:00               2.0
1 1999-01-10 10:00:00 1999-01-10 13:00:00               3.0
2 1999-01-20 17:00:00 1999-01-20 19:00:00               2.0
```

Comment: The only downfall to this code is not taking into account the transitions from 'Date_X 23h' to 'Date_X' 00h. Even though the series isn't interrupted, the code will consider it as so since you're grouping by 1 day.

Comment: I see, that's an interesting edge case! But I'm not sure how to deal with that... Does the other answer address that? @KeyserSoze

Comment: Your answer is much faster on large scale datasets, however Shaido's one corresponds to what I'm looking for.